# GEE filtering featureCollection with a condition

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, feature-collection

I have a dictionary in the form :

```
f_dict = {'A':2, 'B':10, 'C':3, 'X':112, ...}
```

dict.keys() correspond to a GEE featureCollection property. Lets call it 'f_prop'.
dict.values() correspond to the "frequency" of each label in 'f_prop'.
As the matter of fact the dictionary is the result of :

```
fc.aggregate_histogram('f_prop')
```

I am interested to filter the featureCollection (fc) based on 'f_prop' based on the condition that dict.values() are greater/lesser than a number.

I wonder how can I do it in the most GEE-ish way?

Comment: Maybe give an example of the kind of condition you're looking for.

Comment: Lets assume that the condition is : f_dict.values() >= 20